# deployment of azure web app and thier webjobs using VSTS CI/CD

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-web-app-service

I have to publish three web jobs to the Azure web app.
previously I did it through  a visual studio like 
1.select existing web jobs, ok then publish
for three web jobs, I did like that to publish

now I want to automate web jobs and deploy using vsts Ci/cd

Any help much appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to deploy the Webjob with VSTS CI/CD.

you could use the VSTS [Powershell script task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=vsts) with [Kudu WebJob API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API). We could get username/password info from the azure website profile.

[image]

```
https://{userName}:{password}@{WebAppName}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot/App_Data/jobs/{continuous or triggered}/{job name}/
```

For more information about powershell demo code please refer to this [link](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-a-WebJob-using-PowerShell-ARM-Cmdlets).